# Is it possible to re-use a Runnable containing closures

Tags: java, android, multithreading, garbage-collection, libgdx

I'm using [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com) for a game I'm writing, where I have another thread that needs to update the graphics thread.  I was getting crashes as libgdx is not thread safe (intentionally) and I was allowing the other thread to directly modify a variable in the graphics thread.

The [libgdx docs](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationThreading) suggest something similar to the following code.  It's basically a closure containing the incoming information, which is then processed when the graphics thread gets to it.

I've modified it to declare the runnable outside of the the listener in the hopes that I could avoid garbage collection, but it occurs to me that I may have created a race condition now where runnable could be overwritten prior to the graphics thread consuming the previous information?

So far I've been able to avoid garbage collection everywhere else, and my game is also utilizing the low-latency audio bindings in Android so garbage collection is really my enemy.

Any suggestions?

```
private Runnable runnable;
private SomeListener listener = new SomeListener() {
    @Override
    public void messageIn(final String source, final String s, final Object... l) {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { getWorkspace().messageIn(s,l); }
        };
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(runnable);
    }
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've modified it to declare the runnable outside of the the listener in the hopes that I could avoid garbage collection, but it occurs to me that I may have created a race condition now where runnable could be overwritten prior to the graphics thread consuming the previous information?

Yes, this certainly might happen.  Also, you can't use `ThreadLocal`s because it's going to be different threads handling the callback versus the runnable.

What you can do is creating a `BlockingQueue` of the `Runnable` classes.  Once the run method finishes, the `Runnable` could put itself at the end of the `BlockingQueue` to be reused.  When the `messageIn(...)` method was called, it would call `queue.poll()` and only create a new one if there were none in the queue.  This would increase the memory synchronization but lower the GC bandwidth.  It may not gain you much.

You might consider running a memory profiler to make sure this is where you should be concentrating your refactoring to try to lower your memory usage.

Comment: My messages are tiny (keyword and a float or two), so this may be a good option.  I assume that the memory sync cost is proportional to the size of the messages?  And.. oh.. how do I get my closures to work if I'm not in a new Runnable?

Comment: The sync cost is probably a linear cost -- not factored to size of message @DarenSchwenke.  Where to the closures come in?  This is an anonymous class but I don't see any closures.

Comment: using s and l from messageIn within the runnable run call via getWorkspace().messageIn(s,l);  Probably confusing there.  The outer messageIn is a method in my other thread, the inner is a method in the graphics thread.  Making them final in the outer essentially creates a closure when used in the declaration of the new Runnable right... or am I mistaken.  (perl guy who started java about 6 months ago)

Comment: No, closures are java7 thang.  That's just a parameter.  No closures @DarenSchwenke.  Making them `final` just means their value can't change.

Comment: Perhaps I've over-thought this then. Well then if I made a queue of runnables like you said, how do I change the value of s,l within the run methods within each Runnable without new then?  Extend Runnable and add those as private variables?  I'm assuming the 'new' is what is causing the GC.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The queue would hold a `MyRunnable` which `implements Runnable` and has a setter for the s,l. @DarenSchwenke.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are developing a game, I suggest you to post all messages into a Queue, and you do consume then in the game loop as needed.

Comment: right, but how do I create a message without causing the contents to be later garbage collected?  Putting the declaration of runnable inside messageIn accomplishes what you suggest, but causes garbage collection.

Comment: While the reference of it is in the queue it will not be collected. Remove it from the queue, consumes its and the GC may remove the ref after that.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid GC altogether here.  My current GC with this method is 2-5ms every 30 seconds or so, but as I only have 6ms total  available time due to the low latency audio requirement, that's too much.  postRunnable() is the method I have available to properly time my changes to the graphics thread, so the question becomes how do I set up and tear down those Runnables with no GC.  The only time I can really afford to have any GC is during screen changes or when the user pauses the audio in/out.  My simplistic method of making this happen has been to pool and re-use everything until then

Comment: Create a List of Runnables, add new ones forever to the list, when is a suitable time to clean up, remove the finished processes from the List, that should avoid GC.

And if u are doing a game and should post things to the GameThread (infinity loop) you should use a Queue and consumes data in the correct step (probably proccessLogicas(long uptime) os somthing similar)